# get the object properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a code that returns me an object of widgets

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse( xml );

var widgets = from x in loaded.Descendants( "widget" )
              select new
              {
                  URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value,
                  Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value
              };
```

I am trying to create a method that will return the object widgets and then I need another method where I can cal it from and access the values. I am new to C# and using vs2010

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous types cannot easily be shared across methods.

You should make a class to store that data.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse( xml ); 

var widgets = from x in loaded.Descendants("widget") 
              select new // Dynamic/Anonymous class
              { 
                URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value, 
                Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value 
              };
```

It would be better to create a concreate class

```
//Widget.cs
Public class Widget
{
  public string URL { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
}

//Code somewhere else..
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(xml); 

IEnumerable<Widget> widgets = 
              from x in loaded.Descendants("widget") 
              select new Widget()
              { 
                URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value, 
                Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value 
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

change var widgets to dynamic widgets

example

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Sample {
    static object junk(){
        var widgets = new { URL = new Uri("http://test.com/"), Category = "address" };
        return widgets;
    }
    static void Main(){
        dynamic widgets = junk();//var widgets = .. //NG
        Console.WriteLine(widgets.URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: can use widgets.URL, widgets.Category　as is used.

Comment: @Erik suggestion　is better, but Needless to create a class, when to treat remain anonymous class is dynamic type, feel free to use.